# Physics.IgnoreCollision() not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a rigidbody GameObject in scene that changes its physical state via Enum flagging

```cs
public enum ObjState
{
    IgnorePC,
    DontIgnorePC
}
public ObjState m_objState;
```

By this flag and switch statement, I'm attempting to make this gameObject collide or don't collide when need be.

```cs
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    switch (m_objState)
    {
        case ObjState.IgnorePC:
            IgnorePC();
            break;
        case ObjState.DontIgnorePC:
            StopIgnoringPC();
            break;
    }
}

public void IgnorePC()
{
    Collider IO = GetComponent<Collider>();
    CharacterController PC = m_PC.GetComponent<CharacterController>();

    Physics.IgnoreCollision(IO, PC, true);
}

public void StopIgnoringPC()
{
    Collider IO = GetComponent<Collider>();
    CharacterController PC = m_PC.GetComponent<CharacterController>();

    Physics.IgnoreCollision(IO, PC, false);
}
```

However, I'm experiencing inconsistency. Especially, the part where I think I'm misunderstanding the usage of this function when I turn off isKinematic manually and attempt this object to pass through PC with IgnoreCollision().

The reason with me trying to keep this rigidbody non-kinematic and ignore collision at the same time is because sometimes when I want to move this object I still want it to pass through PC. What is going wrong with my method here?

Comment: I tried your code, and on my Unity 2017.3.0f3 it works perfectly fine. I just corrected `Enum` to `enum` (as I did in the edit to your code), and I take the references to the colliders in `Awake` and `Start` (as you should, it's the best practice since `GetComponent` is slow and shouldn't be used when possible outside objects initialization).

Comment: @Galandil Thnks kindly for the edit and answer! My project is in 5.6. I'm hoping the version making the difference here and I think more of my own mistake somewhere I'm not recognizing. Have you tried keeping the rigidbody non-kinematic and ignoring still? I'll refactor those misplaced chaches.

Comment: I've tried just to be sure all combinations on both objects: kinematic+kinematic, kinematic+dynamic, dyn+kin and dyn+dyn, and they all work as intended. I've checked the collisions by dragging the script object in the scene windows toward the other object in the test. 
Can you show with a screenshot the `m_PC` referenced game object Inspector window?

Comment: Wait, I must be still sleeping, now I noticed that you try to pass a `CharacterController` type argument to a `Collider` type parameter.

Comment: @Galandil m_PC is PC GameObject and here was used to ignore ChracterCollider. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Ok I got it, I'll write an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass a `CharacterController` type argument to a `Collider` type parameter of the `Physics.IgnoreCollision` method.

To solve the problem:

- Check (and add if there isn't) a `Collider` on your object with the `CharacterController` component.
- Change your code to this:

```cs
public enum ObjState { IgnorePC, DontIgnorePC }
public ObjState m_objState;
public GameObject m_PC;
Collider IO, PC;

private void Awake() {
    IO = GetComponent<Collider>();
}

private void Start() {
    PC = m_PC.GetComponent<Collider>();
}

private void FixedUpdate() {
    switch (m_objState) {
        case ObjState.IgnorePC:
            IgnorePC();
            break;
        case ObjState.DontIgnorePC:
            StopIgnoringPC();
            break;
    }
}

public void IgnorePC() {
    Physics.IgnoreCollision(IO, PC, true);
}

public void StopIgnoringPC() {
    Physics.IgnoreCollision(IO, PC, false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I've actually tried this and it still did not work where it did not work: Meaning, there's something else here I've made a mistake of. Say PC and objA is there apart from each other. First, I move objA as ObjState.IgnorePC as kinematic rb with MovePosition() it passes through. Second, objA is behind PC as kinematic and when input event happens I make objA non-kinematic rb and still ObjState.IgnorePC also via MovePosition() in PC's forward direction objA hits PC on its back.This is the same when the passed parameter is CharacterController or Collider.

Comment: First of all, you can't at all pass a `CharacterController` type to the `Physics.IgnoreCollision` method as an argument, you'll get an exception shown in the console (but only during runtime, the compiler will not show it as an error). Moreover, if you have that kind of behaviour, then there must be something else setting the collisions back on on your objA. Keep in mind that it doesn't matter if the object's rigidbody is Kinematic or not when collisions are ignored.

Comment: To show that your code works, just create an empty scene, and then create two cubes game objects inside. Attach on both the `rigidbody` component, then on Cube1 attach my script, and on Cube 2 attach a `CharacterController` component. Feed the Cube2 reference to the script, and run the scene: you'll see that when you set the enum to `IgnorePC` and move Cube1 through Cube2 (you can do that in the scene window), Cube2 will stay in its place while Cube1 pass through it, and it doesn't matter if any (or both) rigidbodies are set to kinematic.

Comment: This is soooo strange. First of all, CharacterController in IgnoreCollision() does work perfectly for me(in compiling and running). And the symptoms I experience is picture-perfect same with CC or Collider in the parameter. What should pass through passes through when it does, but just that some case like when the objA is held in position as kinematic and being tossed(moved by MovePosition()) it hits PC and when objA lands it, again, ignores PC. This thing is confusing the living crap out of me bit time.

Answer (score 0):

I think IgnoreCollisions between rigidbodies is broken on Unity 5.6.

Comment: No, sorry, I just did some more tests and compared it to 2017 and it is working OK. I'd make sure if the rigidbody is composed of more than one collider and you want to ignore just part of them, to check if it works OK, as I got some troubles with this. I'm sorry for the previous mislead.